# same git repo, 2 branches, pull to 1 branch does not include changes in other branches

Tags: git, branch, pull

I have 2 tasks to work on 2 source files in one git repo. There is no dependancy of these tasks, I can release either of them first. Given below situation and steps:
`git_repo/file1.json`
`git_repo/file2.json`

create 2 branches:

Command to commit change of file1.json

```
git checkout -b branch1
#do some change on file1.json
git add file1.json
git commit -m 'update file1.json'
git push -u origin branch1
```

Command to commit change of file2.json

```
git checkout -b branch2
#do some change on file2.json
git add file2.json
git commit -m 'update file2.json'
git push -u origin branch2
```

When I new a pull request from branch2 in GUI,
expect: only `file2.json` will be included in the pull request
actual: both changes of `file1.json` and `file2.json` are include in pull request.

How I can get my expecting result?

Comment: Did you check branch2 out of branch1, or out of your main/master branch?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually checkout b2 out of b1, that's the problem. Everything looks good after checkout of master. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's some detail you've left out in your steps, it looks like this is what's happened:

1. You created branch1 from master
2. You added a commit to branch1
3. You created branch2 *from branch1*
4. You added a commit to branch2

If that's the case, then the reason you see file1.json in your branch2..master diff is because of that third step: branch2 is based on, and therefore includes all the contents of, branch1.

You should be able to fix this by running `git checkout branch2 && git rebase master` (or `main`, as appropriate). This will rework branch2 so that it's based on master (or main), instead of on branch1. (You'll also need to do a `git push --force-with-lease` when you push branch2, since the rebase will alter the HEAD of branch2.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually checkout b2 out of b1, that's the problem. Everything looks good after checkout of master. :)